# Uso de servlets java

Tags: java, servlets

Tengo una duda basada en un programa un poco amplio.
Mi programa se trata de gestor de tareas, logistica, registro de usuarios y calendarios.
Estoy usando un servlet (CONTROLADOR) para todos los procesos que realiza el sistema.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente
Es mala practica usar un solo servlet para todo o deberia usar un servlet por cada procesos.
Ejemeplo: Un servlet para tareas otro servlets para usuarios otro servlet para calendarios. Por decirlo asi un servlet por cada entidad.

Gracias a quien me pueda regalar un consejo.

Comment: Un solo controlador para todas las entidades lo hará extenso y difícil de mantener eso sin considerar que si dicho controlador está asociado a tareas particulares de cada entidad yo haría uno por cada de ellas

Comment: Depende, muchos frameworks usan un solo Servlet como punto de entrada (Spring MCV, JSF, Struts), el tema es que ese punto de entrada enseguida delega el trabajo a otros componentes, en el caso de Spring MVC delega a las clases que anotas como @Controller, en el caso de Struts deriva en los Actions. Si seria "mala practica" pretender que un solo Servlet haga todo sin delegar.